# calculate time taken between entry and exit

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of employees entry and exit times, now I want to calculate the time taken by them between entry and exit.

Table:

```
e_id, date, time, type

1, 2021-02-15, 08:00, Entry
2, 2021-02-15, 08:10, Entry
1, 2021-02-15, 11:30, Exit
1, 2021-02-15, 11:35, Exit
1, 2021-02-15, 12:45, Entry
2, 2021-02-15, 16:45, Exit
1, 2021-02-15, 17:30, Exit
1, 2021-02-15, 01:00, Exit
```

### Result:

```
1, 2021-02-15 08:00:00.000 2021-02-15 11:35:00.000 03:35:00

1, 2021-02-15 12:45:00.000 2021-02-15 17:30:00.000 04:45:00

2, 2021-02-15 08:10:00.000 2021-02-15 16:45:00.000 08:35:00
```

The task is group records based on employee id and date, then find out recent entry time and the corresponding exit time before next entry occurs and calculate the time between those. Then order by date and entry time.

As Ihave several entry and exit times, how can I capture responses of this type?

Comment: Have you attempted it? Include the query you have so far.

Comment: @learner Please, review your data. Is it possible that employee whose e_id = 1 had exited two consecutive times without being entered in the meantime. Check it at: `1, 2021-02-15, 08:00, Entry | 
2, 2021-02-15, 08:10, Entry | 
1, 2021-02-15, 11:30, *Exit* | 
1, 2021-02-15, 11:35, *Exit*` .

Comment: @RobertoC.Rodriguez-Hidalgo, yes data is correct, we should ignore the number of matching entry and exit entries in my case. I need to pick latest enty and its exit, and the next entry and the last exit before any new entry occurs.

Comment: OK. Do you mean latest latest entry and its exit in the same day?

Comment: @RobertoC.Rodriguez-Hidalgo, yes lets say records are like e1, x1, x2, x3, e2, x5, x6. where `e` means entry and `x` means exit. The consider e1 to x3 before e2 starts, then e2 to x6.

Comment: @learner Anyway, double check your data because I think it's something missing, probably to define AM or PM. For instance, in your second result how do you determine the exit will be at 17:30:00.000? how do you dismiss 1, 2021-02-15, 01:00, Exit? which is the last record...

Comment: @RobertoC.Rodriguez-Hidalgo, I have to pick the last exit record as 17hrs is more than 1hrs then 17hrs should be picked.

Comment: Consider storing date and time as a single entity

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, for each entry you want the next exit.  If that is the logic, use `lead()`:

```
select t.*, t.next_datetime as exit_datetime
from (select t.*,
             lead(datetime) over (partition by e_id order by datetime) as next_datetime
      from t
     ) t
where t.type = 'entry';
```

At least, this seems to work for the data you have provided.

Note:  I interpret the date/time as being in one column.  It is a bit silly to divide them between two columns.